# Unpredictable WHEA Black Screens

Tags: crash, black-screen-of-death, hp-laptop

Over the last 4 months or so, I have repeatedly had issues with WHEA Error based black screen crashes. As far as customer support goes, I've been given a fair amount of run around between Microsoft and HP, each thinking the problem can only be fixed by the other. The computer I own is a HP ENVY x360 M6 Convertible, a laptop. I have tested my hardware thoroughly using diagnostic tools, and am at my wit's end. The Stop Code provided with the WHEA Error is 0x124, according to WhoCrashed. I would like some help in this matter.
Some additional info: The crashes happen unpredictably, and usually when audio is playing and multiple programs are open and running. I have looked at possible temperature issues but they seem highly unlikely. 
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.